# How to access same complex type element with different child elements from two different XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd

i have two xsd result1.xsd and result2.xsd with different root element say Result1 and Result2 and commons_type.xsd which is included in both the XSDs.

**Result1.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.test.com"
           xmlns="http://www.test.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:include schemaLocation="common_types.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="Result1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="startTime" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                <xs:element name="endTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>                
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>  

</xs:schema>
```

**Result2.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.test.com"
           xmlns="http://www.test.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:include schemaLocation="common_types.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="Result2">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="passingTime" type="xs:dateTime"/>                            
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element> 
</xs:schema>
```

**commons_type.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.test.com"
           xmlns="http://www.test.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>

    <xs:simpleType name="idType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">           
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="unitType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">            
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:schema>
```

I have generated two jars using XMLBeans scomp
result1.jar and result2.jar and imported these jars in eclipse.

I have created two  document object

```
Result1 res1 =  Result1.factory.newInstance() 
Result2 res2 = Result2.factory.newInstance()
```

Now, i want to access startTime and endTime from res1 and passingTime from res2.
But, i am getting startTime and endTime for res2 also.

**Expected is:**

```
res1.setStartTime() ,res1.setEndTime() and res2.setPassingTime()
```

**Actual is:**

```
res1.setStartTime() ,res1.setEndTime() and res2.setStartTime() ,res2.setEndTime()
```